# Mixing object types in a nested array

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm pretty inexperienced with Actionscript 3, and I'm trying to make a nested array with different object types within it, but am having some trouble and wondered if anyone can help.

I want to create a nested array where the first element of the *parent* array is an array of movieclip instances that exist on the stage, but then the second and third elements of the parent array are arrays of string objects. This is what I'm trying:

```
var objectArray:Array = [   [instance1, instance2, instance3],
                            ["word1",   "word2",   "word3"],
                            ["word4",   "word5",   "word6"]   ];
```

However I receive runtime errors such as this:

> TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "word1"
>   to flash.display.MovieClip.

As far as I'm aware, object types can be mixed in arrays, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and endless searching online has not proved fruitful. Do any clever people out there have any idea what my problem is?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with mixing types like you have done - the error you're getting is related to what you're *trying to do* to the objects in your arrays.

My guess is that you're iterating over the inner arrays using a `for each` loop that is typed incorrectly, for example:

```
for each(var i:MovieClip in objectArray[1])
{
    // Error - objectArray[1] holds objects which are not MovieClip.
}
```

Or you might even just be trying to type cast the objects in a normal loop, which would give the same error:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < objectArray[1].length; i++)
{
    // Error.
    var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(objectArray[1][i]);
}
```

Mixing types in an array is generally not a good idea (one of the reasons being this scenario). If you update your question to explain why you're doing this, I can update my answer to explain a better way of going about it.

Comment: I used for loops to iterate through the 1st element of the parent array, but I haven't done any type casting in the for loop. My array definition occurs outside the loop as above.

The goal is to test for collisions between movieclips in the 1st child array, storing info about collisions in the other two child arrays. I used nested arrays as it seemed logical as the info in each child array corresponds with info at the same index of the other child arrays. There's nothing to stop me using separate arrays if it's better practice, but I'd like to understand what I'm doing wrong here still.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I had simply made a mistake in how I was indexing the array. Silly me!